# How to discretize this integral equation? (Langevin Eq)

Tags: discretization

I am trying to build my own simulator of Langevin Equation for the Brownian motion.

According to this [material](http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~ingves/Teaching/TFY4275/Downloads/kap6.pdf).

The way we calculate the particle position in certain time step is :

[image]

W(u) is a Wiener process. x0, v0, tauB are all constant.

My question is: How to write a c++ code for this Wiener process integral equation?

This is the code that I currently used in the simulator.

```
N=1000;
tau=0.1;      //0.1s
t=N*tau;
tauB=m/gamma; //~ 1e-8s

for(int j=0;j<=N;j++){  // t step
        sum=0;
    for(int k=0;k<=j;j++){  // u step
        sum=sum+(1-exp(-(j-k)*tau/tauB))*ND[j]*tau
    }
    x[j]=x0+v0*tauB(1-exp(-j*tau/tauB))+tauB/m*sum
}
```

x[j] is the particle position at time step j.
ND[j] is a Normal distribution random value at time step j.

dW(t)=dU(t)=ND(t)dt.

The result is incorrect.
There must be something important that I misunderstood in the equation.

Please help me.

Comment: Is your code actual code or are you using C as pseudo code? You're using square braces as parentheses in multiple places.

Comment: If your goal is to simulate this, it might be more straightforward to write out the SDE and use Euler-Maruyama. You also might find this answer of mine on Math.SE helpful: [Implementing Ornstein–Uhlenbeck in Matlab](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1288406/80812).

Comment: My fault, I should write it more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The increments, $W(t_{k}) - W(t_{k-1})$, of the Brownian motion $W(t)$ are normally distributed with zero mean and variance equal to $t_{k} - t_{k-1}$.  If ND[j] is a normal random variable with zero mean and variance equal to one, then you want to multiply it by sqrt(tau).  The resulting ND[j] * sqrt(tau) is a normally distributed random variable with zero mean and variance equal to $t_{k} - t_{k-1}$, which is what you want.

Comment: Ah.... yeah, that is a my typo. Let me change the description. Sorry.

Comment: I can see that you have edited the code but the symbol N coincides with the upper bound in your loop (N=1000) and, besides that, the factor tau is still present (it should not be).